# Is it possible to calling OData4 service with post request containing xml body?

Tags: xml, postman, odata, odata-v4, xml-to-json

I have an xml body and I want to invoke the "odata" web server by sending a post request. But when I edit the content-type with **application/xml** or **application/atom+xml**, I get the error message "invalid json type for an entity". Is it possible to post xml to call OData v4 endpoint?

Comment: It depends on the endpoint you are calling. Looks like that endpoint support only json

Comment: have you any idea about "$format" query option. If I use this option can i call OData service by posting xml?